# Microsoft SharePoint Upload files from Java

Tags: javascript, java, unix, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there any feasible way of uploading files  into Microsoft SharePoint via Java code under specific folder.
Guide me to upload the files in Microsoft SharePoint pragmatically , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can upload documents through the copy web service on SharePoint.  This can be found at http://<Site>/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx where <site> is the URL of your SharePoint site.  You will need to use the CopyIntoItems() method and specify the URL of the folder in the DestinationUrls parameter.  The tricky part will be authenticating, which will depend on the version of SharePoint you have and the authentication method you use.